# Метод Ньютона для решения нелинейных уравнений

Tags: алгоритм, c++

Вечер добрый.
Мне было дано такое задание: реализовать метод Ньютона для решения нелинейных уравнений, чтобы в итоге на экран выводилось: значение неизвестной, количество итераций, потребовавшихся для нахождения решения, а также время затраченное на нахождения ответа.
Я попробовала написать:

```
//#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

float f (float);
float df (float);
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    float x0,xk,a,b,e;
    int  count = 0;
    cout<<"Vvedite à:"<<endl;
    cin>>a;
    cout<<"Vvedite b:"<<endl;
    cin>>b;   
    cout<<"Vvedite x0:"<<endl;
    cin>>x0;   
     cout<<"Vvedite e:"<<endl;
    cin>>e;
    while ( fabs(xk-x0)> e )
    {
        xk=x0-((f(x0))/(df(x0))) ; 
        cout << count <<"-iter = " << xk << endl;
        count++; 
    }
    getch();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
float f (float x)
{
    // func
    return (exp(x)+ x*x -2);

}

float df (float x)
// dif funk
{
    return (exp(x)+ 2*x );
}
```

Но проблема в том, что цикл получается бесконечный и в связи с этим с количеством итераций проблема. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как исправить? И Что добавить, чтобы выводило время в наносекундах?

Comment: вопрос на засыпку: а чем у вас итерации отличаются?  
хинт: на каждой итерации вы вычисляете одно и то же.

Answer (score 1):

**По Методу Ньютона:**

Как Вам верно написал [@Yura Ivanov](/users/6117/yura-ivanov), у Вас в цикле одно и то же вычисление происходит. Ни `xk`, ни `x0` не обновляются. Естественно, цикл будет крутиться вечно.

**По замеру времени:**

В наносекундах :) Почему не в [аттосекундах](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D1%82%D1%82%D0%BE-) ?

В миллисекундах обычно замеряют время алгоритмов. Дело в том, что в Windows системные счетчики обновляются примерно каждые 10 миллисекунд. Поэтому, простыми средствами, точнее чем милиисекунды получить не получится.

По идее, миллисекунд должно хватить. Замеряется время очень просто, например, так:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    DWORD before = ::GetTickCount();
    // тут долгий цикл
    DWORD after = ::GetTickCount();
    std::cout << "Long loop lasts: " << (after - before) << " millisecond";
}
```

Есть, конечно, в Windows и более точные таймеры. Если вам действительно они нужны, ботайте функции: [QueryPerformanceCounter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644904%28VS.85%29.aspx) , [QueryPerformanceFrequency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644905(v=vs.85).aspx)  из WinAPI.

Почитайте, также, статью [Implement a Continuously Updating, High-Resolution Time Provider for Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163996.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Давеча было дело. `f` это ваша функция, `Derivative` - производная.

```
private static double Derivative(Func<double, double> f, double x)
{
  return (f(x + Eps) - f(x))/Eps;
}

public static double NewtonMethod(Func<double, double> f, double x)
{
  if(f == null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException("f");

  int iters = 0;
  double y = f(x);

  while(Math.Abs(y) > Eps)
  {
    if(iters >= MaxIters)
      throw new InvalidOperationException("Too many iterations");

    x -= y/Derivative(f, x);
    y = f(x);

    iters++;
    Console.WriteLine(y);
  }

  Console.WriteLine("Iters = {0}", iters);

  return x;
}
```

ps. Корень, в методе Ньютона локализовывать не надо (переменные `a` и `b` в Вашем коде не к месту)

Comment: `Derivative(f, x)` подразумевает вычисление производной от `f(x)`? или первый аргумент просто лишний и производная хардкодится также как и `f`?

Comment: Насчет вычисления производных вспомнилась отличная статья ["Автоматическое дифференцирование "на пальцах" "][1]

[1] : http://habrahabr.ru/company/intel/blog/170729/

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, обновил ответ

Comment: @Veikedo слишком большая ошибка в вычислениях, но мысль понял. спасибо.